# How to get Top 10 for a grouped column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

My data is a list of customers and products, and the cost for each product

```
Member    Product    Cost
Bob       A123       $25
Bob       A123       $25
Bob       A123       $75
Joe       A789       $50
Joe       A789       $50
Bob       C321       $50
Joe       A123       $50
etc, etc, etc
```

My current query grabs each customer, product and cost, and also the total cost for that customer. It gives results like this:

```
Member    Product    Cost    Total Cost
Bob       A123       $125    $275
Bob       A1433      $100    $275
Bob       C321       $50     $275
Joe       A123       $150    $250
Joe       A789       $100    $250
```

How can I get the top 10 by Total Cost, not just the top 10 records overall? My query is:

```
SELECT a.Member
    ,a.Product
    ,SUM(a.Cost)
    ,(SELECT SUM(b.Cost) from MyTable b WHERE b.Member = a.Member) as 'Total Cost'
FROM MyTable a
GROUP BY a.Member
    ,a.Product
ORDER BY [Total Cost] DESC
```

If I do a `SELECT TOP 10` it only gives me the first 10 rows. The actual Top 10 would end up being more like 40 or 50 rows.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you purposfully using the same table (MyTable ) twice in the query or is this a typo?

Comment: It's on purpose. MyTable is the only table I'm using. I'm using the select within the select to get the total cost for each member.

Comment: What if there are ties among different members?

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for the replies. Obviously I can't use everyone's answer, but I did learn a lot from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```sql
SELECT tbl.member,
       tbl.product,
       Sum(tbl.cost)       AS cost,
       Max(stbl.totalcost) AS totalcost
FROM   mytable tbl
       INNER JOIN (SELECT member,
                          Sum(cost) AS totalcost,
                          Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Sum(cost) DESC) AS rn
                   FROM   mytable
                   GROUP  BY member) stbl
               ON stbl.member = tbl.member
WHERE  stbl.rn <= 10
GROUP  BY tbl.member, tbl.product
ORDER  BY Max(stbl.rn)
```

Online Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/87857/1/0

---

Table structure & Sample Data

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
 member  NVARCHAR(50),
 product NVARCHAR(10),
 cost    INT
)

INSERT INTO mytable
VALUES ('Bob','A123','25'),
       ('Bob','A123','25'),
       ('Bob','A123','75'),
       ('Joe','A789','50'),
       ('Joe','A789','50'),
       ('Bob','C321','50'),
       ('Joe','A123','50'),
       ('Rock','A123','50'),
       ('Anord','A100','50'),
       ('Jack','A123','50'),
       ('Anord','A123','50'),
       ('Joe','A123','50'),
       ('Karma','A123','50'),
       ('Seetha','A123','50'),
       ('Aruna','A123','50'),
       ('Jake','A123','50'),
       ('Paul','A123','50'),
       ('Logan','A123','50'),
       ('Joe','A123','50');
```

Subquery - Total cost per customer

```sql
SELECT member,
       Sum(cost) AS totalcost,
       Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Sum(cost) DESC) AS rn
FROM   mytable
GROUP  BY member
```

Subquery: Output

```
+---------+------------+----+
| member  | totalcost  | rn |
+---------+------------+----+
| Joe     |       250  |  1 |
| Bob     |       175  |  2 |
| Anord   |       100  |  3 |
| Aruna   |        50  |  4 |
| Jack    |        50  |  5 |
| Jake    |        50  |  6 |
| Karma   |        50  |  7 |
| Logan   |        50  |  8 |
| Paul    |        50  |  9 |
| Rock    |        50  | 10 |
| Seetha  |        50  | 11 |
+---------+------------+----+
Record Count: 11
```

Main Query

```
SELECT tbl.member,
       tbl.product,
       Sum(tbl.cost)       AS cost,
       Max(stbl.totalcost) AS totalcost,
       Max(stbl.rn)        AS rn
FROM   mytable tbl
       INNER JOIN (SELECT member,
                          Sum(cost) AS totalcost,
                          Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Sum(cost) DESC) AS rn
                   FROM   mytable
                   GROUP  BY member) stbl
               ON stbl.member = tbl.member
GROUP  BY tbl.member, tbl.product
ORDER  BY Max(stbl.rn)
```

Main Query: Output

```
+---------+----------+-------+------------+----+
| member  | product  | cost  | totalcost  | rn |
+---------+----------+-------+------------+----+
| Joe     | A123     |  150  |       250  |  1 |
| Joe     | A789     |  100  |       250  |  1 |
| Bob     | C321     |   50  |       175  |  2 |
| Bob     | A123     |  125  |       175  |  2 |
| Anord   | A100     |   50  |       100  |  3 |
| Anord   | A123     |   50  |       100  |  3 |
| Aruna   | A123     |   50  |        50  |  4 |
| Jack    | A123     |   50  |        50  |  5 |
| Jake    | A123     |   50  |        50  |  6 |
| Karma   | A123     |   50  |        50  |  7 |
| Logan   | A123     |   50  |        50  |  8 |
| Paul    | A123     |   50  |        50  |  9 |
| Rock    | A123     |   50  |        50  | 10 |
| Seetha  | A123     |   50  |        50  | 11 |
+---------+----------+-------+------------+----+
Record Count: 14
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this. This is the answer I ended up going with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use rank() and partition by but you may also need to use a window function:

```
with temp as (
     SELECT a.Member
    ,a.Product
    ,SUM(a.Cost)
    ,(SELECT SUM(b.Cost) from MyTable b WHERE b.Member = a.Member) 
    as 'Total Cost'
    FROM MyTable a
    GROUP BY a.Member,a.Product
)
select a.*, rank() over (partition by member order by [Total Cost] 
  desc) as rank
from temp a
order by rank desc limit 10
```

Comment: this will only return 10 rows.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala I thought he only wanted the top 10, if not he can remove the limit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dense_rank() like below. Worked in SQL Server 2016. Change the value of limit variable to filter number of rows returned.

```
declare @limit int = 10;
SELECT *
FROM
(
  select x.*,rn = dense_rank() over (order by x.TotalCost desc)
  from (

    SELECT a.Member
        ,a.Product
        ,SUM(a.Cost)
        ,(SELECT SUM(b.Cost) from MyTable b WHERE b.Member = a.Member) as 'TotalCost'
    FROM MyTable a
    GROUP BY a.Member
        ,a.Product
    ORDER BY [Total Cost] DESC

  ) x
) y
where rn <= @limit
order by rn
```

Comment: 2016, probably was a typo. thanks for the warning. @marc_s

Answer (score 2):

Use a subquery to get the TOP 10 total costs and join to your query:

```
SELECT
  t.Member, t.Product, t.Cost, g.[Total Cost]  
FROM (
  SELECT Member, Product, SUM(Cost) as Cost
  FROM MyTable 
  GROUP BY Member, Product
) t INNER JOIN (
  SELECT TOP (10) Member, SUM(Cost) as [Total Cost]
  FROM MyTable 
  GROUP BY Member
  ORDER BY [Total Cost] DESC
) g on g.Member = t.Member
ORDER BY g.[Total Cost] DESC, t.Member, t.Cost DESC
```

Depending on your requirement you may use:

```
SELECT TOP (10) WITH TIES...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dense_rank()` with `apply` :

```
select mt.*
from (select mt.*, sum(mt.Cost) over (partition by Product, Member) as Cost,
             dense_rank() over (order by TotalCost desc) as seq 
      from MyTable mt cross apply
           (select sum(mt1.Cost) as TotalCost
            from MyTable mt1 
            whete mt1.member = mt.member 
           ) mt1
    ) mt
where mt.seq <= 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't have to select from the same table twice. Use `SUM OVER` to get the total per member.
2. Use `DENSE_RANK` to get the totals ranked (highest total = 1, second highest total = 2, ...).
3. Use `TOP(10) WITH TIES` to get all rows having the top ten totals.

The query:

```
select top(10) with ties *
from
(
  select
    member,
    product,
    sum(cost),
    sum(sum(cost)) over (partition by member) as total_cost
  from mytable
  group by member, product
) results
order by dense_rank() over (order by total_cost) desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `SUM OVER` .. it will help me in other things as well!

Answer (score 2):

If you want *exactly* 10 customers even when there are ties, then a slight variation on Thorsten's method will work:

```
select top(10) with ties t.*
from (select member, product, sum(cost) as cost,
             sum(sum(cost)) over (partition by member) as total_cost
       from t
       group by member, product
      ) t
order by dense_rank() over (order by total_cost) desc, member;
```

The addition of `member` as a second key may seem like a minor addition.  However, it ensures that the `dense_rank()` is unique for each member (of course ordered by `total_cost`).  This, in turn, guarantees that you get exactly 10 customers.